# Keyboard pressing using wxpython

Tags: python, keyboard, wxpython

I need to make a key on the keyboard (like letters) get pressed.
I have the values for the keys in wxpython but I can't get them to get pressed.
I need some sort of function that uses the value of the key and make it being pressed.

thank you all :)

Comment: I don't think `wxpython` will do this for you. You may need to use a system call, in which case we need to know what OS you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about wxpython having the capability to make that happen however I know that you can do it with pywinauto and it's extremely simple.

Something like:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
app.Notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
```

will make notepad open and then will send it the key shortcut to close it.

https://pywinauto.github.io/